# Are eigenvalues of finite multiplicity isolated?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I am studying the proof of mini-max principle for self adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces and I know that on this situation, isolated elements of the spectrum are eigenvalues. My question is: is true that eigenvalues of finite multiplicity are isolated elements of the spectrum? I could not prove it but the book I am studying "Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space" by Konrad Schmüdgen, appears to claim it.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not true at all.  It's quite possible to have eigenvalues embedded in continuous spectrum.  For example, consider the operator of multiplication by $x$
on $L^2([0,1],\mu)$ where $\mu$ is the sum of Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and a point mass at $1/2$.  Or somewhat more generally, take a direct sum 
Hilbert space $\mathcal H = \mathcal H_1 \oplus \mathcal H_2$ and self-adjoint operator
$T = T_1 \oplus T_2$ where $T_1: \mathcal H_1 \to \mathcal H_1$ has continuous spectrum on some interval, while $T_2: \mathcal H_2 \to \mathcal H_2$ has a point in that interval as an eigenvalue with finite multiplicity.